# What is the appropriate capacity of a matching step down transformer for a power amplifier?

Tags: voltage, transformer, power-amplifier

I have a **TRIO KA-9900 amplifier** which is the Japanese equivalent of a **KENWOOD KA-907 amplifier**.

My amplifier runs on Japanese AC voltage.

What is the **appropriate capacity** of a **step-down transformer** for **use in a country that runs on 230v**?

Here are the specifications:
AC 100V
400W
50/60Hz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 230 to 100VAC stepdown transformer should be rated at 400 watts or more. Remember that at normal listening volume levels the power requirements will be much lower than 400 watts. If you use a much larger transformer like 2000 watts it is still safe. However the larger transformer has more iron and hence will waste more power at light load. Say if the transformer magnetising power loss is 2 % then the 400VA transformer wastes 8 watts and the 2000 watt transformer wastes 40 Watts. These losses are relevant if you are playing at low volume 24/7. If you go smaller which I do not endorse then the stepdown transformer may overheat at high audio output power and cause droop in the 100 VAC meaning that the Amp will not produce its rated output power anyway. If you must skimp on the stepdown transformer then thermal protection is compulsory.

Comment: I will not go below 400W. I wanted guidance to ensure I play it safe and I am not wasteful either. Your in-depth explanation has been most helpful. In other words a 500VA is a pretty good choice.

Comment: Please stop putting space before period!

Answer (score 1):

When compared to a step-down transformer, a 500VA autotransformer would be more compact, lightweight and economical.

[image]

It would be required to be housed in an enclosure, properly earthed and with appropriate plugs/sockets for 230V~ and 100V~.

Comment: Never knew such a thing existed. I have purchased a 500VA step-down transformer already. But I deeply appreciate your pointing this out to me, I checked one out on Amazon.

Comment: Anytime, ElectronicsNewbie!